# How does the Community user close a question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I did search but couldn't find an answer... so hope this isn't an exact duplicate... as that would be rather embarrassing.

I saw a question closed today by two users, and ***Community* ♦**.

At what point does the Community user decide to get in on the act?

Is it some kind of literal string for string comparison?

Comment: It means the OP agreed that it is a duplicate. It's a confusing convention that I wish they would change.

Comment: @sumelic Aha thanks, now I understand.

Comment: @sumelic it was actually introduced not far ago, and you can find out the reason by hovering over the link. (It's in the tooltip)

Comment: Community is kind of a control freak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is all explained on Meta.SE: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/323179). Here's a summary:

When there is at least one duplicate close vote on their question, the author sees a banner:

> [image: This question may already have an answer here: dupe link]

Clicking on that button (and confirming) closes the question as a duplicate.

---

### Why Community?

Shog9 explains in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes#comment819394_250960):

> Although the effect is the same in this (one, narrowly-defined) scenario, question owners **do not** have binding close votes on their own post - I believe such a feature would likely introduce a great deal of confusion unless also coupled with binding reopen votes, which would of course introduce either an opportunity for abuse or a ton of extra rules for voting. The system is closing the question, not the user who confirmed the duplicate.